Websocket in API NodeJs
I'm building a exercise focus on a chat system (for hobby), using:

Backend: NodeJS, Express, MongoDB, JWT and WebSocket
Fronted: React, Tailwind

The structure of the API is this

I want to know, how is the best way to implement WebSockets in the API. i read some examples of Websockets with Socket.io, but all the logic is in the App.JS file. Exists others ways for a better implementation (for example, create a "websocket.js" file with all the basic logic for the app. (like customs hooks in react)

You can create like a service, create one controller, router, etc.. and you can start the connection when the user send a request, something like "start chat', OR you can keep the socket servers always live, starting the server in the app js.
